# NodeJS i18next and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, i18next

Anyone has been able to use the `i18next-node-mongodb-backend` module when a MongoDB authentication is required. The documentation of the module states the following:

```
var i18next = require('i18next');
var Backend = require('i18next-node-mongodb-backend');

i18next
  .use(Backend)
  .init({
    backend: options
  });
```

I used the `host`, `port`, `db`, and `collection` options. However, is it possible to also specify a user and a password?

```
i18next
    .use(mongoBackend)
    .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        backend: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 27017,
            db: 'my_database',
            collection: 'my_collection',
            // authentication option?
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Instead of using host, port, db separately you could try to use the uri option: https://github.com/gian788/i18next-node-mongodb-backend#backend-options

Answer (score 1):

By looking into the code of i18next-node-mongodb-backend I can confirm the above mentioned comment. The only way to solve this, is to use the uri parameter => https://github.com/gian788/i18next-node-mongodb-backend/blob/master/lib/index.js#L52

The uri should be composed like this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```